# Joomla PHP command line script fails

Tags: php, joomla

I have a command line test script that runs locally OK, but when I try to run it on my host (Bluehost) through ssl (using Putty) it fails, but doesn't throw an error.

I've checked the error logs and there is nothing there to indicate a failure and I have turned on E_ALL errors there.

On my local wamp server this runs fine and outputs all the prompts:

```
1. environment imported
2. About to execute!
3. Got instance
4. Success
5. Finished executing!
```

When I run this over putty at my host it outputs only the first two lines.
    1. environment imported
    2. About to execute!

This is the script (joomla 3.4.5):

```
<?php
// Initialize Joomla framework
const _JEXEC = 1;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

// Load the configuration
require_once JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php';

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';


echo "1. Environment imported\n";

class Test extends JApplicationCli
{
public function doExecute()
    {
         echo "4. Successful execution\n";
    }
}

echo "2. About to execute\n";

$test = JApplicationCli::getInstance('Test');
echo "3. Got instance\n";

$test->execute();
echo "5. Finished executing!\n";

?>
```

I have tried running this with different variations of the command line:

```
php jwjtest.php
php54s -c ~/public_html/php.ini ~/public_html/cli/jwjtest.php
```

I have also surrounded the line that executes 'getInstance' with 'try' and 'catch' but no error is caught.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Please turn on errors with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script and tell us what is being shown (on your server, that is).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about ini_set. However, I added those and the result is the same. I tried testing by adding in a syntax error (missing semicolon) and that created a response `Status: 500 Internal Server Error` back to the command line, with the syntax error appearing in the error log.

Comment: I also tried just now running the script with a -c option to point it at a php.ini file which has error reporting set to E_ALL and display errors on, but I don't get any error output on the console or in the log.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that from the command line I have to use the command line version of PHP. On Blue host you have to initiate that by using php54-cli (php-cli doesn't work) .. so for example for my test case I ran

```
php54-cli jwjtest.php
```

and everything worked OK.

I am not sure why just using php as the command didn't work (perhaps it ran the wrong version of php?) but at least I now have solution. 
I was set on the right track to this from a reply that I got on joomla.stackexchange from user1104799